# how can I import subfolders module python to another file?

Tags: python-2.7

I want to access to my modules.module function A in my main , but when I do this I have an error that I cannot import that.. how can I fix it? I Have seen multiples articles but  i hadnt a chance, how can I fix this error of importing modules from subfolders?

```
**/tool
  main.py
/google
   /modules
   __init__.py
   module.py**
```

**ImportError: cannot import name google**

main.py

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys
import core.settings
from google.modules import google


if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        core.settings.settings()
        google()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print "interrupted by user.."
    except:
        sys.exit()
```

module.py

```
def google():
    print 'A'
```

Answer (score 0):

the easiest way to work this out is have your `main.py` in your highest directory (it makes sense anyway for main to be there) and if you really want the real main to be in a sub directory have a dummy main at the top level you can call that just calls the actual main, that way python can see your entire directory tree and will know how to import any sub directory.

**alternatively**

you could add your parent directory to the sys.path:

```
parent_dir = os.path.realpath(os.path.join(os.getcwd(),'..')))
sys.path.append(parent_dir)
```

which will add that directory to the places python searches for when you try to import stuff.

but then you will need to keep track of how deep your main is in the directory tree and its a pretty unelegant solution in my opinion

Comment: I did it )) , one question will I always need __init__?  how can I import for example fromt google.google import A in __init__ , but extends on google once

Comment: i dont understand what you're asking